# How to move tr into tbody using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table

```
<table id="table1">
  <tr class="fixedHeader">
    <td>Head1</td>
    <td>Head2</td>
    <td>Head3</td>
    <td>Head4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

i need to move the `tr` into `tbody` except the tr which has `fixedheader` class. I need to do this in javascript or jquery only.

Any help guys

Comment: `$('tr:not('.fixedheader')').wrap('tbody');`

Comment: So basically, your `td` elements inside `.fixheader` should be `th` elements. And you should use `thead` for the header. That's the expected behaviour you are looking for, i guess...

Comment: Yes, `thead` should be used, otherwise there'll be `tbody` inside `tbody`

Comment: Why don't you render formely relevant HTML markup? I mean, why do you want to use js/jq to do that?

Comment: FYI, Chrome automatically adds a `<tbody>` inside a table which doesn't have one. You should fix the HTML at the root, rather than monkey-patching it with jQuery

Comment: If changing HTML structure is not possible, use http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vnq6nyco/1/

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the browser does this for you: it wraps all the `<tr>` that are not in either `thead`, `tfooter` or `tbody` into `tbody`. So what you need to do is this:

```
var $thead = $('<thead>').append($("tr.fixedHeader")).prependTo($('#table1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classList.contains to check class exist by javascript

```
<script>
var table = document.getElementById('table1');    
var tbd = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];  
var thead = document.createElement("thead");
table.appendChild(thead);
for(var i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++) {
var trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];    
var tr_class = trs.classList.contains("fixedHeader"); //return true when class exit if not return false
if(!tr_class){           
    tbd.appendChild(trs);
}
else{
    thead.appendChild(trs);
}
}       
</script>
```